# ALTER columns from multiple tables in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to change same column name with same column type in multiple tables in one query?

something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE 
(SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'data_by_%_month_%'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA='db_name') 
MODIFY column1 INT(20) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with `ALTER TABLE` alone. It is expected for the `ALTER TABLE` statement to receive one table.

See [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html). It doesn't expect an expression there.

You can of course write a program that creates multiple `ALTER TABLE` statements based on your `SELECT` Query.

Comment: my example was pseudo statement, something I would like to have as option. I can do some king a loop, but I want this to be done in one query if possible

Comment: @dzona look into creation of functions and try to solve it. If you come into problems ask a new question because thats an entirely different problem.

Comment: Of course it is possible to make a workaround, but I wanted to discuss whether it is possible to obtain an elegant solution for this interesting problem.

Comment: @dzona Well, unfortunately its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a stored procedure.

**Example**:

***Test table structures***:

```
drop table if exists so.tbl_so_q23631366_1;
drop table if exists so.tbl_so_q23631366_2;

create table so.tbl_so_q23631366_1( column1 varchar(10) );
create table so.tbl_so_q23631366_2( column1 text );
```

***Stored Procedure***:

```
drop procedure if exists modify_column;
delimiter //
create procedure modify_column()
begin
  declare no_more_to_fetch boolean default false;
  declare alter_table_string varchar(1024) default '';
  declare alter_stmts_crsr cursor for 
    select concat( 'alter table ', table_name
                   , ' modify column1 INT(20) NOT NULL default 0;' )
      from  information_schema.tables
     where  table_name like 'tbl_so_q23631366%' -- 'data_by_%_month_%'
       and  table_schema='so'; -- 'db_name';

  declare continue handler for not found 
      set no_more_to_fetch = true;

  open alter_stmts_crsr;
  Result_Set: loop
    fetch alter_stmts_crsr into alter_table_string;
    if( no_more_to_fetch ) then
      leave Result_Set;
    end if;

    -- un comment following line to debug
    -- select alter_table_string;

    set @sql := alter_table_string;
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    drop prepare stmt;
  end loop Result_Set;
  close alter_stmts_crsr;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

***Call stored procedure***:

```
call modify_column;
```

***See modified table structures***:

```
desc tbl_so_q23631366_1; desc tbl_so_q23631366_2;
```

Answer (score -2):

No. You can only list one table name in the `ALTER TABLE` clause, though you can alter more than one item in a table:

From [MySQL docs on ALTER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c, DROP COLUMN d;

Comment: Question is how to alter one column from multiple tables, not multiple columns in one table

Comment: @dzona, no, your question was "Is there a way to change same column name with same column type in multiple tables in one query?" The answer is no. Answered.