# how to add a new column to multiple mysql tables at once

Tags: mysql, field, multiple-columns

I have a MySQL Database containing 100 tables.
I want to add 2 fields in all those 100 tables at once.

fields are `'created_by'` and `'modified_by'.`

any suggestions...

Comment: Use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to construct the appropriate `ALTER TABLE` statements.  Then execute them.

Comment: I [answered a similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23632567/767881). You may not require an SP, but you can make use of it with minor change, like `alter .... add column created_by ...`

Comment: Do i have to run this query 100 times?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to do this.  Instead, construct the SQL queries and then run them.  Something like this:

```
select concat('alter table ', t.table_name,
              ' add created_by varchar(255), add modified_by varchar(255)'
             )
from information_schema.tables t;
```

Then copy the code into the appropriate tool and execute it (use use `prepare`).

I would also recommend that you at `created_at` and `modified_at`, if these are not already present.